# Issue exiting video after playing(ios phonegap app)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk, cordova

I am currently using iwebkit and phonegap together. Once everything is compiled and tested on an idevice, I can click a video link and get it to play. It play full screen but it uses the ios web video player (the one that doesn't have the "done" button" and the top and has a bar that spans the bottom of the screen. I can then press the full screen button to have it use the regular ios media player but when i click done from that, it doesn't take me back to the part of the app before the video, it just takes me to the full screen video in the web player. I hope someone can help me solve this and I hope I was able to describe my problem in a clear way. I've spent 2 hours searching and have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. iOS 4.3.x introduced this problem as far as I can tell. There's a few comments about it on Apple's developer site but so far I haven't found any solution. Part of the problem seems to be Phonegap because I experience the exact same thing you describe when running the compiled app. However, if I simply browse to the same HTML pages it seems to work fine. Note - I changed from directly linking to video files to using the HTML5  tag. Using the tag works better than direct linking in Phonegap -- the videos still open in the player but when you click the Done button it returns to where it was. Keep in mind that if you do this the video will be on the inline in the page and paused but when you click the play button it opens in the player. The only problem I've found with this solution is that it won't rotate when you change from portrait to landscape when running in the phonegap app but it does rotate when browsing to the video in mobile safari. Not sure if any of that helps. I would be interested in what you've been able to work out since you posted.